# Navigate / access docker-machine file system

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to access the file system of a container made with `docker-machine`. I've used the [ssh command](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/) but it doesn't seem to have anything that will allow you to list files / folders (like `ls`).

How would one explore the files currently on a container with `docker-machine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bash session(assuming your image has bash installed) in a  RUNNING container with the following command.

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> bash
```

Then you can explore the filesystem of the container.